# How to make a new line in javascript in a single string

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make new lines (in this single line of text) as you can see in my index.html file, but it is not working, any help? (\n is where the new line should start, 
 has not worked either.

index.html:

```
<html>
        <head>
                <title>test</title>
        </head>
<body bgcolor="black">
<font color="green">
<p id="terminal"></p>
<script>
var text = "this is a test\nthis should be on the next line";
var count = 0;
var speed = 50;
function Type() {
        if(count < text.length) {
                document.getElementById("terminal").innerHTML += text.charAt(count);
                count ++;
                setTimeout(Type, speed);
        }
}
Type();
</script>
```

Comment: `<br>` instead `\n`

Comment: White space is ignored when you set the `innerHTML` of an item. You can use `<pre>` to keep the white space inside of it's tag instead of `<p>`.

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz I tried telling about how that did not work but stackoverflow saw it as actual html code, when I use <br> it shows up: this is a test<br>this should be on the next line

Comment: @Jimenemex so how would I go about doing this?

Comment: You've just completely changed your question, to the point where the existing answers don't make sense. Please don't do that.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan yes, I solved my issues which then gave me another, I did not see a reason not to do this.

Comment: Because it shows a complete disregard for the people who have answered your original question? Please read [ask]. If you have another question, ask a new question.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use `<br />` you can easily use the `<pre>` tag. It's actually easier to use `<pre>` since you don't have to insert the `<br />` at the right location in the DOM.

Taken from the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre).

> The HTML pre element represents preformatted text which is to be presented exactly as written in the HTML file.

```js
var text = "this is a test\nthis should be on the next line";
var count = 0;
var speed = 50;

function Type() {
    if(count < text.length) {
        document.getElementById("terminal").innerHTML += text.charAt(count);
        count ++;
        setTimeout(Type, speed);
    }
}
Type();
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>test</title>
  </head>
  <body bgcolor="black">
    <font color="green" />
    <pre id="terminal"></pre>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Substitute the  new line `\n` with break `<br>`